# How to update Xamarin Data Binding when source changed

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding

I have 2 labels which are data bound to an object on my profile overview page, lets assume:

```
public class Profile
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName {get; set; }
}
```

I have a profile edit page which allows the user to make changes to the properties. In the View Model for this page we are passed the Profile object and we make a clone of this so we are able to Cancel any changes without affecting the data bound labels if the user chooses not to Save.

However, when the user saves the changes the cloned Profile object gets passed back to the calling View Model, now how can I update the original Profile object using the cloned one as something as simple as:

originalProfile = clonedProfile;

does not work as the data bindings are not updated which is expected behaviour. So short of manually updating property by property, what's the best way to achieve this so the data bound controls are updated ?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` both in Model and ViewModel so that the UI will update in runtime .

#### in ViewModel

```
public class xxxViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


  
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


   

    Profile _originalProfile ;

    Profile originalProfile { 
        
        get
        {
            return _originalProfile ;
        }

        set
        {
            if(_originalProfile !=value)
            {
                _originalProfile = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("originalProfile");
            }
        }
    }




}
```

#### in Model

```
public class Profile: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
  
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    string firstName ;

    string FirstName { 
        
        get
        {
            return firstName ;
        }

        set
        {
            if(firstName !=value)
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }

    string lastName ;

    string LastName { 
        
        get
        {
            return lastName ;
        }

        set
        {
            if(lastName !=value)
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

You could add a method in Profile

```
// 
void UpdateValue(Profile newValue)
{
  this.FirstName = newValue.FirstName;
  //...
}
```

Now in ViewModel you just need to invoke it like following .

```
originalProfile.UpdateValue(clonedProfile);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but that's not it. I have INPC implemented but this does not work when you "hot swap" the binding source. INPC only updates the bound controls on the UI when the and individual property is updated.

Comment: You could  set  `originalProfile.FirstName  = clonedProfile.FirstName ;`

Comment: Yes, I realise I can do this and with the example I gave is very simple, but for this project there are many properties and not just 2. I was just wanting to know if there was a better way rather than setting each property ?

Comment: Check my update answer .I think it is a better way with encapsulation .

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I was hoping there was going to an easier way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218867/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-henda79).

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as the only other option was to answer it myself, and since my answer would be the same as Lucas', as there does not seem an alternative apart from setting each property one by one.